# "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations" android

Tags: android, firebase

```
Process: mishelb.app.globe_all, PID: 11971
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(CustomClassMapper.java:478)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(CustomClassMapper.java:330)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:61)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
    at com.example.globe_all.SignupScreen.updateUI(SignupScreen.java:92)
    at com.example.globe_all.SignupScreen$2.onComplete(SignupScreen.java:77)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

So I have this in my log. I am using android studio and Firebase, and after trying to

```
mDataBase.child(keyID).setValue(u);
```

I get this error code.

Here is the entirety of the code:

```
    package com.example.globe_all;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class SignupScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final String USER = "user";

    private EditText user, email, pass, passRep;
    private Button signup;
    private User u;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_screen);

        user = findViewById(R.id.user);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.password);
        passRep = findViewById(R.id.pass_repeat);
        signup = findViewById(R.id.signu);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        mDataBase = database.getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getText().toString()) &&
                        TextUtils.isEmpty(pass.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(passRep.getText().toString())) &&
                        pass.getText().toString().equals(passRep.getText().toString())) {

                    u = new User(user.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(),
                            pass.getText().toString());
                    registerUser(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
                }


            }
        });
    }

    public void registerUser(String email, String password) {


        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    Log.d("FAIL", "process failed");
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void updateUI (FirebaseUser currentU) {

        String keyID = mDataBase.push().getKey();
        u.setId(keyID);
        assert keyID != null;
        mDataBase.child(keyID).setValue(u);
        Intent login = new Intent(this, LoginScreen.class);
    }
}
```

After attempting the solution provided by
Ticherhaz, still get the error:

```
Process: mishelb.app.globe_all, PID: 8895
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(CustomClassMapper.java:478)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(CustomClassMapper.java:330)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:61)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
    at com.example.globe_all.SignupScreen.updateUI(SignupScreen.java:89)
    at com.example.globe_all.SignupScreen$2.onComplete(SignupScreen.java:75)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of the class that contains the `isChangingConfigurations` field.

Comment: That's the thing - I don't have any class doing that

Comment: At which particular line of code does it occur?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out - I didn't have get() and set() methods set up for my User class, but now I have another problem.
The data is just not being added to the realtime database. I mean, I'm doing everything correctly, but I don't see it being displayed in the database.

Comment: kk I got the answer for that as well. I searched for it, and some guy you need to add the database url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers, I finally figured it out.
In turns out the database requires my User class to have get() and set()
methods for each of the class' properties.
After setting these up, and inserting my realtime-database URL in:
`database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(URL);`
It finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

You re-set back the `setId`. You are suppose to use the `param` itself.

At the `onClick` you comment this line `object`. So it will become like this.

```
 if (!(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getText().toString()) &&
      TextUtils.isEmpty(pass.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(passRep.getText().toString())) && pass.getText().toString().equals(passRep.getText().toString())) {
      //Comment this line 
      //u = new User(user.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
      registerUser(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
 }
```

And then at the `updateUi` method, you create the `User` object.

```
public void updateUI (FirebaseUser currentU) {

    final String keyID = mDataBase.push().getKey();
    final User userToDB = new User(keyID, user.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
    mDataBase.child(keyID).setValue(userToDB);
    Intent login = new Intent(this, LoginScreen.class);
}
```

UPDATE

Since the error regarding your `User` class, related with `isChangingConfigurations`. You need to rename the `variable` since this is reserve to the `Firebase`

Change

```
isChangingConfigurations
```

to

```
isChangingConfigures
```

Comment: Did it, still throws the same exceptionIt says the problem is in the `mDataBase.child(keyID).setValue(usertoDB)`

Comment: @Gu5t4v what does error says ?

Comment: Still the same error as earlier, hold on, I'll put it here